# Spring MVC Testing Error in loading xml fie

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, spring-test

My Code is works, but it fail in Junit mock testing in the below line.

ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../MyFile.xml");

HOw do I fix this?

adding @ContextConfiguration or is there another way?

"ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../MyFile.xml");"  This line is in the normal method **not in the test class**

Comment: "fail" is a bit unspecific -- what do you mean by "fail", for example, which exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your problem exactly is, since you already mentioned both solutions, but of course you can choose between either putting it on testclass by annotation with

```
@ContextConfiguration( locations = { "../applicationContext.xml" } )
```

or initializing it by method beeing annotated with @BeforeClass, so the server gets started just once before all tests in this class like the following example:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp()
{
  ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "../applicationContext.xml" );
}
```

Maybe you need to explain what exactly fails when initialising your ApplicationContext.